# MVC Loading up a modal with dynamic model information on click

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, modal-dialog

Still a little bit new to MVC but trying to setup a modal that receives dynamic data depending on where the table data is in the foreach loop.

We have a partial that we are using to generate our table code and are passing the viewmodel we need to this partial. Now within the partial we want the links on a certain column to display a modal corresponding to that row when you click on them. So basically hand off that row's model data and display the more detailed data in the modal. For example, here we are displaying the count of the companies effected but in the modal I want to be able to display the names of them. So I need to pass that on somehow.

**Table Code :**

```
@model IEnumerable<Tier2BugViewModel>

<table id="bug" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" width="100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th data-class="expand">Bug</th>
            <th data-hide="phone">Companies Effected</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @{
            foreach (var row in Model)
            {                            
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#bugEditModal">
                            Edit
                        </a>
                    </td>
                    <td>@row.Bug.Bug</td>
                    <td>
                        <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#companiesEffectedModal">
                            @row.CompaniesAffected.Count
                        </a>
                    </td>
                </tr>             
            }
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**Modal Code :**

```
<!-- Companies Effected Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="companiesEffectedModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="companiesEffectedModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    @Html.Partial("_CompaniesEffectedModal")
</div><!-- /.modal -->
```

After some research it feels like we are going to need some sort of jQuery script to do this, but I can't put my finger on it or figure out if there is just an easier way to do this. I guess we will eventually be doing this for the Edit modal as well. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Pass a unique Id for the row in the querystring & make an ajax call to load the content for the modal dialog. In the action method which returns the content for the modal dialog, get the data again using the id you passed. Here is some sample code to load bootstrap modal using ajax with unique urls. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38983904/loading-model-in-modal-works-only-once

Comment: Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39495226/how-to-load-selected-partialview-in-a-view-in-asp-mvc/39495858#39495858), you will find solution.

Comment: @Shyju I'm looking at the response you mentioned but I can't seem to figure out how to retro fit that to my situation. Maybe this is just my naive understanding of MVC but I can't see where the unique urls in that situation are even being created. Any added insight?